# How do I get my Ubuntu web server to host on the internet?

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, internet, nodejs

As far as I know this isn't a duplicate, but I may be wrong. Anyways, my Ubuntu server is running a NodeJS Application and it seems to run fine. I just put in the local ipv4 address in the browser followed by port 8000 and it works perfectly. Buuuuut not anywhere else besides my local network. I know the reason for this is because I need to use my router ip: 98.240.50.79. So after realizing that I went to go port forward port 8000 on the local ip, but it still didn't work. I'm getting no connection to the server through the browser and the Node server itself is receiving no get requests. So please keep in mind the following.

- I've already port forwarded
- I'm using port 8000 on the server
- The local ipv4 is 10.0.0.233
- The router ip is 98.240.50.79
- I've already added the router ip in the /etc/hosts file

Comment: So from the outside world you type in 98.240.50.79:8000 and get what response?

Comment: It just times out.

Comment: Either port forwarding is misconfigured or your ISP wont you let you use port 8000. For testing purposes you could try forwarding port 80 (probably not blocked) to 10.0.0.233 port 8000.

Comment: You can't use port 80 in NodeJS, it just spews out errors at you.

Comment: Yes, but atleast you would know if the traffic reaches the destination or not

Comment: Typically, you can redirect ports too within your setup.  If your router allows it, you could try port 80 to 8000.  It's dependent on the hardware though.

Comment: At my router port forwarding is called virtual servers (used to mistaken it with port triggering) so are you sure you did it right? Can you try an apache server or xampp at port 80 to make sure if its forwarding or the nodejs problem?

Comment: The NodeJS won't run with port 80, but yeah LAMP doesn't work at all either.

Comment: Then you would have to read routers manual or ask this question in more suitable forum :)

Comment: There is no router manual -_-... I've hosted things before in the same manner an had no problem so it's not router specific and this is the suitable forum...

Comment: God please don't be another Stack Overflow (even though I know the layout is the same people are so stupid or are complete jerks on there)

Comment: As you mentioned earlier, the traffic didn't get throuh port 80 either, but everything works in local network, so it is router problem. Sometimes it's necesary to reboot the router after making changes.

Comment: Router's problem indeed. Can you take as screenshot of the port forwarding at  your router settings an upload it to http://imgur.com/?

Comment: http://imgur.com/FF1lHvE

Comment: It seems correct. Are you sure you have static ip on your internet (not the local but the router ip)? Use this https://whatismyipaddress.com/ to make sure it hasn't changed.

Comment: Yeah I can't use dynamic ip's because of all my servers (a few games and an Apache server).

Answer (score 0):

Try ti open on port forwading section on router your port.

So go to router ip:

- port forwading section;
- add tcp rule at your ipaddress
- open browser and write your
  externalip:port .

In /etc/host remove the external ip if this last is dynamic.

Comment: It doesn't do anything different.

Comment: Mmm have you a dedicated firewall ?

Comment: No I don't. I am just hosting this server on a VM so I know what to do when I build my actual machine.

Comment: Mm is the network interface a NAT ?

Comment: It says abriged adapter.

Comment: Uhm.. And in router obivously you open port of the bridge ip address, isn't really ?

Comment: Yes I port forwarded the ip address...

Comment: Sorry if the questions are stupid but i want understand to help you..

Comment: Ahh it's fine mate I just appreciate the help!